# How to play video files in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to play video file in qt. But when i am using `QMediaPlayer` Class, it is throwing an error as : `fatal error: No such file or directory.`

```
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;

    QMediaPlaylist *playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/myclip1.mp4"));
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/myclip2.mp4"));

    QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
    player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

    videoWidget->show();
    playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
    player->play();
```

When i am including `QMediaPlayer` class it is throwing error.

I am using Qt4.8.4 Version, Ubuntu 12.04 in my system

Comment: which qt version, which operating system, which sdk version/install?

Comment: I am using Qt4.8.4 Version, Ubuntu 12.04 in my system

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that QMediaPlayer is a feature in 4.8.4?

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html

It looks like it has been introduced with Qt5.

Check out this example for 4.8.4 video playback:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-qmediaplayer.html

Comment: I checked above example. But here too <Phonon/VideoPlayer> is not present

Comment: Have you tried installing the QtSDK? This seems to be an environment problem, so please search the NET for HOWTOs on how to setup your Qt environment. Going with the SDK should be the easiest, alternatively, see posts like http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/54625-How-to-use-phonon-on-Ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, this is not a place for 1to1 support, checkout http://qt-project.org/downloads to get a current version of the SDK. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Add to the .pro file:

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += multimedia
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the videoplayer from here, I didn't try it, but it might help you: http://radekp.github.io/qtmoko/api/phonon-videoplayer.html: